# Is there any way to find center item position on ListView in Flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to find center item position on ListView while scrolling without depending on the width (horizontal list) of the item.

I has try formula: notification.metrics.pixels / itemExtent to find first item on screen.

But It not true in my case, there is a item has itemExtent bigger than other. Therefore, Is there any way to find center item position without depending on the itemExtent of the item.
Thanks.